How to make a (very) temporary RAM disk?
Ideally I need to create a RAM disk just over the lifetime of a python script. That is, the script creates a RAM disk, uses it, and at the end, destroys the RAM disk and gives back its resources to the OS. Is this possible? Or is a reboot required?
I have a rack server that contains over 170 GB of RAM, giving sufficient elbow-room. How quickly can a RAM disk be created on it, and then unmounted and have its resources given back to the OS?

Python has a tool for the described use of RAM-only: https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.SpooledTemporaryFile

By default /dev/shm is available to all users. Simply write whatever data you want there, and clean up afterwards.
/dev/shm employs tmpfs, which is not pure RAM-disk. If sufficient memory pressure exists it may be written to swap.
You can change the size of it as well.
